# On connected image of a disconnected domain

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Q.5 Let݂ $S=[0,1)\cup [2,3]$ and $f:S\to R$ be a strictly    increasing  function    such that  $f(S)$ is connected. Which   of  the following   statements  is  TRUE?
(A) ݂$f$ has exactly one discontinuity.

(B)݂$f$ has  exactly two discontinuities.

(C)݂$f$ has  infinitely  many    discontinuities.

(D)݂$f$  is  continuous.

Can someone give some hints how to tackle this problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:**

1. The connected subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are intervals. (might be open, closed, half open, bounded, unbounded, it doesn't matter. They are intervals). How can you describe the image of $f$ then?
2. Because the function is increasing it has one sided limits at every point.

Try to combine both hints and it will get you to the solution.

Comment: Therefore it has to be connected I think. The first components will map to some interval. As limit from left exist so the image of the second component will start exactly where the first component ends. Is it ok ?

Comment: Good start. So what can you conclude about the continuity of the function?

Comment: The function should be continuous.

Comment: Yes, it is correct. Because the image is the interval $[f(0),f(3)]$ and the function is increasing it is easy to conclude that at each point $x$ the one sided limits must be equal to each other and $f(x)$ is a number between the values of these two limits. Because the one side limits are equal we get that $f(x)$ equals to the limit at the point $x$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind attention